# Update "survey-angular" to "survey-angular-ui"

Tags: angular, npm-package, surveyjs, npm-update

My angular project contains following packages:

```
"survey-angular": "^1.9.4",
"survey-creator": "^1.9.4",
"@angular/cdk": "11.0.1",
"@angular/common": "12.0.3",
```

How should I update "survey-angular" to "survey-angular-ui"?

My Angular project has multiple libraries, which are creating conflicts while I try a few ways.

1. I tried 'npm update survey-angular', but this did not change anything in the package.json
2. I tried directly changing the package.json from "survey-angular" to "survey-angular-ui" and then npm install.

Comment: Have you tied uninstalling `survey-angular` then installing `survey-angular-ui`?

Comment: Yes, I tried uninstalling survey-angular then installing survey-angular-ui. But now I am checking whether the conflicting packages are causing any problem. Thank you